# hackerrank password cracker timeout due to recursion

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, backtracking, memoization

[This problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/password-cracker) simply restated is this: given a bunch of strings and a target string, what all combinations from the given string can combine together to form target string with and without repetition.

e.g.

**strings**: we do what we must because we can

**target**: wedowhatwemustbecausewecan

**output**: we do what we must because we can

Approach I took is to remove every longer word from the target until target becomes empty. If targets becomes empty then just return the output. If longer words doesn't lead to a solution then try with shorter words and so on. I am also using memoization to make sure that if the target is already tried then just return, same as backtracking with memoization.

This apporach passed all the testcases except 2, where I am getting timeout.

```
def recursions(word_map, paswd, output, remember):
    flag = 0
    if len(paswd) == 0:
        return 1
    if paswd in remember:
        return flag
    for char in paswd:
        for word in (word_map[char] if char in word_map else []):
            if paswd.startswith(word):
                output.append(word + " ")
                if recursions(word_map, paswd[len(word):], output, remember):
                    return 1
                output.pop()
        remember[paswd] = 1
    return flag
```

Please help in providing a **hint**. Complete solution is [here](https://ideone.com/XgFlVk).

Comment: The code looks correct, except perhaps you'd have problems if the recursion goes too deep. But debugging problems on stackoverflow require a specific problem and reproduction of the problem in the question.

Comment: Try to switch to pypy. Though the timeout for pypy is much lower than for python, in some cases you won't exceed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try dynamic programming approach where you mark the ending locations of each password. Start by trying every password at the beginning of the longer string. If it fits there mark down the ending position in the longer string. You could then repeat the same process for every location in longer string where previous location is marked as ending position.

Hope this helps you getting started, I've intentionally left out some of the information required for full solution so let me know in comments if you're still stuck.

**EDIT** Here's a short example on what I'm talking about. It doesn't allow you to reconstruct the solution but it shows how to do the matching without recursion:

```
passwords = ['foo', 'bar']
login = 'foobar'

ends_here = [False] * len(login)

for i in range(len(ends_here)):

    # Match password at the beginning or if password match
    # ended to previous index
    if i == 0 or ends_here[i - 1]:
        for pw in passwords:
            if login.find(pw, i, i + len(pw)) != -1:
                ends_here[i + len(pw) - 1] = True

print(ends_here)
print('We can match whole login attempt:', ends_here[-1])
```

Output:

```
[False, False, True, False, False, True]
We can match whole login attempt: True
```

**EDIT** Took a closer look at the code provided in the question. The issue is on the line where matched strings are filtered by the characters contained in  the target: `for char in paswd:`. Instead of doing filtering for every character in the target string the filtering should be done for every **unique** character: `for char in set(paswd):`. Fix that and solution runs much faster but would probably be even faster if there wouldn't be that kind of filtering at all since the maximum number of shorter strings is 10.

Comment: can you elaborate more as I am doing very similar to that in my recursive approach?

Comment: @user3053970 Added short example on how to do the matching without recursion. You need to modify it though so that you can print the passwords in case there's a match,

Comment: @monster You're correct but that was intentionally left out since the question was asking hint, not a full solution.

Comment: oh sorry. deleted my comment so no worries:)

Comment: @user3053970: Added explanation why the code provided in the question is so slow compared to example in the answer.

Comment: @niemmi: What do you mean by this:probably be even faster if there wouldn't be that kind of filtering at all since the maximum number of shorter strings is 10 and their length is capped to 10 ? Once ends_here is used then it wouldn't really matter as the algorithm will go through all ends_here indexes to reach the target.

Comment: @niemmi: also this doesn't make sense "if i == 0 or ends_here[i - 1] != -1:". I tested it without that and it works fine. I think you wanted to break out early as any password in any order will be done so once we reach the end of the array that means we already found the solution. I think we can use that fact.

Comment: @user3053970: You're correct it doesn't make sense, there was a bug that I've fixed now. If you try with `passwords = ['oo']` and `login = 'ooooo'` you can see the behavior is different before and after the change.

Comment: @user3053970: What I mean with the statement is that the solution would be faster if you'd just pass the list of words to `recursions` and then just check for every word if it's a prefix of `paswd`.

Comment: @niemmi: Thanks. Why are you not breaking out early https://ideone.com/ciDLTd and afterwards ends_here list can be used for the solution as any combination is acceptable.

Comment: @user3053970: You could break out and that would speed up the solution in some cases. It would require keeping track of max index `x` where `ends_here[x]` is `True` though which would add couple lines. I wanted to provide the simplest example that illustrates the principle so it was left out.